# How to append a second query to each result row?

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs, express

I am using express and mysql to query all projects.

```
app.get('/api/projects', (req, res) => {
    const { name } = req.query;
    let whereString = '';
    if (name) {
        whereString = `WHERE projects.name LIKE '%${name}%'`;
    }

    connection.query(`
        SELECT projects.*, owner.name as owner
        FROM projects
        LEFT JOIN owner ON owner.id = projects.owner
        ${whereString}
        ORDER by projects.created_on DESC
    `, (err, results) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.send(err);
        } else {
            return res.json({results});
        }
    })
})
```

each project has comments that are stored in an own table `comments` where each row has the `projects.id`. How can I expand my code to run a `SELECT * FROM comments WHERE project = ##projectid##` to each result of my first query and expand the result with a {comments: { // comments... }}?

Currently I'm getting:

```
{
   "results":[
      {
         "id":180,
         "name":"CaCr",
         "created_on":"2020-08-19T10:48:13.000Z",
         "owner":"Tom"
      },
      {
         "id":178,
         "name":"NX"
         "created_on":"2020-08-19T10:45:01.000Z",
         "owner":"Max"
      },
      {
         "id":177,
         "name":"Windchill",
         "created_on":"2020-08-19T10:44:35.000Z",
         "owner":"Karl"
      }
   ]
}
```

and I expect to recieve:

```
   "results":[
      {
         "id":180,
         "name":"CaCr",
         "created_on":"2020-08-19T10:48:13.000Z",
         "owner":"Tom",
         "comments":[
            {
               "id":1,
               "comment":"foo"
            },
            {
               "id":2,
               "comment":"bar"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":178,
         "name":"NX",
         "created_on":"2020-08-19T10:45:01.000Z",
         "owner":"Max"
      },
      {
         "id":177,
         "name":"Windchill",
         "created_on":"2020-08-19T10:44:35.000Z",
         "owner":"Karl",
         "comments":[
            {
               "id":3,
               "comment":"foobar"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected result

Comment: Why don't you use Sequelize ORM? It has options to include associations while querying and you won't have to write raw queries